# qt isn't detected by qtcreator

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, coda

I'm triing to get a simple application to work on symbian (Nokia N97)
I installed qt 4.7.4 and qtcreator 2.3.1 on my pc
I installed qt 4.7.4 and CODA 4.0.23 on N97

when i run the application from qtcreator i get the error:

```
Executable file: 9124 2011-10-23T16:37:36 C:\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian1Qt473\\epoc32\release\gcce\udeb\untitled.exe
Connecting to 'COM4'...
Connected.
Launching: untitled.exe
Launch failed: Command answer [command error], 1 values(s) to request: 'C|38|Processes|start|""|"untitled.exe"|[""]|[]|true' 
#0 {"Code":-1,Format="Failed to create the process (verify that the executable and all required DLLs have been transferred) (item not found)"}
Error: 'Failed to create the process (verify that the executable and all required DLLs have been transferred) (item not found)' Code: -1
Finished.
```

when i check the device info in qtcreator: projects > symbian devide > run > Device (info)

```
Qt version: Not installed on device
ROM version:v 30.0.004 16-06-11 RM-555 (c) Nokia
CODA version: 4.0.23
Qt Mobility version: 1.2.0
Qt Quick components version: Not installed
QML Viewer version: Not installed
Screen size:640x360
```

the qt version isn't installed
i did install the qt.sis in my qt sdk folder:

```
"C:\QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^3\Qt\4.7.4\qt.sisx"
```

What am I doing wrong?

--------------EDIT--------------
i tried installing qt for symbian^1:

```
"C:\QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^1\Qt\4.7.3\qt.sis"
"C:\QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^1\Qt\4.7.3\qmlviewer.sis"
"C:\QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^1\Qt\4.7.3\qtwebkit.sis"
"C:\QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^1\QtMobility\1.1.3\qtmobility.sis"
```

the last 2 give the error:

```
update failed (no device)

something went wrong
An error occurred on installation of the file- Foutcode: 2153775107- (in ovi suite)
```

I probably need to use CODA, cause trk isn't supported in qt creator 2.3
so i install:

```
"C:\QtSDK\Symbian\sis\Symbian^3\CODA\public_coda_installer_1-0-5_build2_signed.sis"
```

then i try to run the application from qt creator:
error:

```
Launch failed: Command answer [command error], 1 values(s) to request: 'C|8|Processes|start|""|"test1.exe"|[""]|[]|true' 
#0 {"Code":-1,Format="Failed to create the process (verify that the executable and all required DLLs have been transferred) (item not found)"}
Error: 'Failed to create the process (verify that the executable and all required DLLs have been transferred) (item not found)' Code: -1
```

In qt creator: device info:

```
Qt version: **Not installed on device**
ROM version:v 30.0.004 16-06-11 RM-555 (c) Nokia
CODA version: 4.0.23
Qt Mobility version: 1.2.0
Qt Quick components version: Not installed
QML Viewer version: 1.0.0
Screen size:640x360
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The N97 is a Symbian^1 (5th Edition) device, not a Symbian^3 device, but you mentioned that you tried to install the Symbian^3 version of the qt.sisx.

Look for the Symbian^1 version of the qt.sisx file on your PC and try installing that on the N97 instead.

You should be able to find that sisx file in the Qt SDK Start Menu folder (named Install Qt 4.7.3 for Symbian^1 on device'). If it is not there you may need to run the SDK maintenance tool to update your SDK.

Comment: thx for the help: added results to first post. still not working

Comment: do i have to use CODA or the AppTRK to transfer the files?, cause AppTRK isn't supported anymore by QT creator 2.3.

Comment: i tried again on a symbian^3 phone with coda and everything works, thx for the help